# Populate SharePoint Contact List with AD user information

Tags: list, active-directory, contacts

I want to import user information (contacts) from Active Directory (AD) and populate contact list in Sharepoint 2010.

I bet the easiest way is to import contacts from outlook. However, this will not update any changes made in employee information. Hence, I want to populate and sync these contact list from AD.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SharePoint server you can use the User Profile Service to sync your user's properties with AD. Then instead of using a contacts list just use the user list in SharePoint. This list I find serves better as your corporate contact list as it does provide real info (from AD and from user's updating their own info) and with enabling my sites you can find out more about the users.

If you don't want to go this route, you'd have to create a timer job or maybe a script with PowerShell to handle the sync'ing.

Answer (score 0):

You can Synchronize the active directory user with the SharePoint custom list using LDAP :-)

if you want web part then go link below :

http://www.4cinfoengg.com/sharepoint-portfolio/AD-user-management-sharepoint-2010-webpart.html