# Create SharePoint Contacts List From AD

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

A similar thread already exists but I do not have much experience with the SharePoint User List (in fact never heard of it!). The thread is here:
[Populate SharePoint Contact List with AD user information](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35791/populate-sharepoint-contact-list-with-ad-user-information)
I have the user profile service up and running but we do not use My Sites. I essentially want a list that shows all users from AD, can be filtered easily and obviously needs little to no maintenance in way of staying up to date with amendments in AD. Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with timer job? I have a solution then.

Comment: Would this list be accessible to standard users? Have you considered the huge security risks with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend going for Search to avoid development and keep your environment supported, not to mention - automatically updated, no need to handle that yourself. With or without My-Sites configured, as long as you have User Profiles + Synchronization running, via Search + People vertical you could build up a whole new experience to your users, and benefit from advanced Filters (e.g. I build a Isotope by creating my own Display templates, similar to Pinterest +  Filters). Examples are abundant - have a look at [this series](http://sympmarc.com/series/create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-employee-directory-on-office365/) from Marc A. - and it works perfectly on-premises too.

Comment: You don't have to use My Sites to take advantage of user profiles. For SharePoint to really work, you must be syncing the data from AD already, so you've got that data to work with.

Comment: @MarcDAnderson - I did mentioned "with or without" - right ?

Comment: You did! Sorry about that.

Comment: Guys, thanks, this has sent me in the right direction. One issue I have is that my people scope is empty! I know my AD profiles are being crawled as I can see them in central admin. I have seen a thread stating that I have to update the content source with a sps3:// URL for the MY SITES but I do not have MY sites!? any ideas

Comment: Ignore this...figured out that the crawl account did not have access to the user profile service application.

Answer (score 0):

User lists are a no no. Avoid that!!

Figure out if you have all the fields that you need in AD.

Create a SharePoint Contact list with all the fields you need.

Figure out if you can map all the fields from AD to Azure AD coz some of them are not possible to map if you cant get them to Azure AD.

Make a power Shell script that takes the fields and populates into SharePoint.

Make the power Shell script as a Schedule task.

Take a look at [this](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/integrating-sharepoint-2013-with-azure-active-directory-part-1-configuration/) article.

Comment: Using sp2010 Ent